# Changing the length of one row of a multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
class B {
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        int x;
        String aa[][]= new String[2][2];
        aa[0]=a;
        x=aa[0].length;
        for(int y=0;y<x;y++)
            System.out.print(" "+aa[0][y]);
    }
}
```

and the command line invocation is

**`>java B 1 2 3`**

and the option was

> 1.) 0 0
>
> 2.) 1 2
>
> 3.) 0 0 0
>
> 4.) 1 2 3

I told 2nd option will be correct, since array was declared with `[2][2]`, so it can't be something like `[0][2]`. But, answer is `1 2 3`. anyone explain this, how this happen ??

Comment: Have you tried it in a debugger to see how this happens?

Comment: i'm executing this using command prompt

Comment: @coders then run it in a debugger and see what it is doing.  Downvoted as poor research effort.

Comment: Multidimensional array is an array of references at from 1st to (n - 1)th dimensions. So you can freely change the reference any time.

Comment: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1162 might provide some insight

Comment: @coders good question !!, i don't why, people said poor research effort.

Comment: Such a great question!! More upvotes!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arguments of the program are stored into `aa[0]` which is an array because `aa` is an array of array.

So the program just really iterates over the arguments of the `main` method. It prints `1, 2, 3` (it does not care about `aa[1]`).

```
int x;
String aa[][]= new String[2][2]; // create an matrix of size 2x2
aa[0]=a; // store the program arguments into the first row of aa 
x=aa[0].length; // store the length of aa[0] which is the same as a
for(int y=0;y<x;y++) // iterate over aa[0] which is the same as a
    System.out.print(" "+aa[0][y]);
```

Is the same functionally as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    System.out.print(" " + a[i]);
// or even
for (String str: a)
    System.out.print(" " + str);
```

**Edit**

As stated someone that has since deleted his answer (you shouldn't have, I was upvoting it while you deleted it), java multi-dimensional arrays are jagged-array, this means that multi-dimensional arrays does not have to be of the same size, you can have row 1 and row 2 having 2 different sizes. So, it means that declaring a `String[2][2]` does not means that row needs to be limited to only two columns when you reassign a row.

```
String[][] ma = new String[3][2];
ma[0] = new String[] {"a", "b"};
ma[1] = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}; // valid
String[] foo = new String {"1", "3", "33", "e", "ff", "eee"};
ma[2] = foo; // valid also
```

Comment: To whom thought the answer was wrong: do you mind explain ... ?

Comment: @coders, Whoever downvoted has withdrawn it; If this answer works for you, go ahead and accept. (Otherwise, elaborate on what's still unclear.)

Comment: I think the question that still needs resolving is 'What is the expected behaviour during the assignment of 'aa[0]=a' that causes it to ignore the array size from the 'new' statement?'

Comment: @Kieveli yeah you got the exact question.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `aa` is declared as an array of array of string, as opposed to simply a multi-dimensional array. When you set `aa[0] = a` you are setting the first element of the array of arrays to the string array passed as arguments. Therefore, when you iterate through the items of `aa[0]` you are iterating through the items that were placed there in the `aa[0] = a` statement.